# SQL Server - Monitoring Data Without Relying on Normal Distributions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, monitoring

I currently have several stored procedures monitoring different aspects of data within my database server. While I have emails and failure notices on various processes, a successful process does not guarantee that the data itself is correct.

For example: processing rules may cause some data to be rejected for what appears to be valid reasons, however, the rejection rates are incredibly high on a given day due to spam from an outside source. This should be flagged so that we can reach out to correct this issue as quickly as possible to reduce overhead on our servers.

The monitors that I have currently, use Normal Distributions that use a certain period of Historical data for each monitor type. A status of "Yellow" is given when yesterday's data is outside of 2 deviations and "Red" when it is outside of 3.

The issue I have is that many (almost all) of these monitors will flag as "Yellow" every day and several will flag as "Red" when there is no issue. I believe this is due to my data not being Normal.

My question is:
Are there better methods to monitor data than the Normal Distribution and, if so, can research material be supplied to point me in the right direction?

I have found this http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/data+monitoring/137257/ which is very interesting as a starting point. Other searches tend to return Normal Distribution type results.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, before you start assuming your data is normal and creating processes that rely on normality, it's probably best to test for normality.

Normal distributions have skew and kurtosis values that are close to zero. In general, if a set of data have a skew between -1 and +1, then the skew of the data is normal. If a sample has a kurtosis value between -4 and +4, then that's probably fairly normal.

Doing a quick google search, I found [this procedure](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/skewness-and-kurtosis-part-3-another-t-sql-solution/) for calculating skew and kurtosis in transact-SQL, yet I have not tried it.

If your data is normal for any particular column, then using standard deviation is probably reasonable. That said, keep in mind that in a normal distribution, 5% of all values will lie beyond -2 and +2 standard deviations of the mean, and about 0.5% of all values will lie close to or beyond -3 and 3 standard deviations of the mean. Therefore, you shouldn't be surprised when you're getting a decent number of cautions and warnings even with "normal data".

The other thing to keep in mind is whether you're looking at the distrubution of a sample or population. If you're comparing yesterday's data to means for all historical data (i.e., population metrics), then that's entirely different than comparing to a sample of the past month's data. If you're using a rolling sample (e.g., the past 30 days of data), you'd want to ensure that your rolling sample is large enough to adequately represent the population you're comparing against.

If your data turns out to not be normal, then you're probably better off building a table with caution and warning points for each data point you collect. There is an entire set of statistical analyses that could be used to determine statistically significant changes from your desirable data, but many of them are fairly complex and may not be easy to replicate using T-SQL logic.

All of that said, it sounds like SQL Server 2016 is going to be right up your alley as it supports integration of R, which supposedly makes it much easier to run complex statistical analyses on your data.

Let me know if you have any other questions!